# Android Scene Transition Animation(target UI is RecyclerView)

Tags: android, animation

Start a Activity :

```
    ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            (Activity) context,
            new Pair<View, String>(view.findViewById(R.id.iv_content),
                    ArtDetailAdapter.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE),
            new Pair<View, String>(view.findViewById(R.id.tv_art_name),
                    ArtDetailAdapter.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE_NAME));

    ActivityCompat.startActivity((Activity) context, intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
```

The target activity is contain recyclerView. So I set transitionName is viewHolder:

`ViewCompat.setTransitionName(vpImages, VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE);
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(tvArtName, VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE_NAME);`

The image of target activity was contained in viewPager.

The Scene Transition Animation is suck(background became black for a second) When I launch target activity. Look the gif for detail.

But When I press back menu the scene transition animation is nice.
Why?

[image]

[Image for question detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MicSI.gif)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?